# Find pixel width after Horizontal Stretch

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using a third party control called TimelineTool for WPF and on load i want the timeline to stretch the width of the Grid column i have specified.

This is how a Timeline row is used:

```
<tt:TimeLineControl Height="115"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UsedTemplateProperty}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    x:Name="TimeLine2"
    UnitSize="20"
    MinimumUnitWidth="20"
    Background="Blue"
    DrawTimeGrid="True"
    MinWidth="300"
    SynchedWithSiblings="True" d:IsHidden="True" />
```

As you can see a MinWidth is set here and also HorizontalAlign="Left".

In the C# code I am retreiveing the MinWidth property from this element and using it as a startup width.

```
 double setWidth = MinWidth;
```

**Is it possible to set the MinWidth to the value of HorizontalAlign="Stretch"?**

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` instead of `Left`?

Comment: @MikeEason Because it still takes the MinWidth so the element moves to the middle and is 300px wide.

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do with the `UnitSize`?

Comment: @MikeEason Sorry i should of said that UnitSize is just there to display lines on the timeline.

Comment: Unless there's something in the control template for that thing making it not stretch implicitly, or if the parent panel it's embedded in is implicitly restricting it. There's no reason it shouldn't consume the grid column space provided. I'd set your MinWidth on your Column instead of the object if it's an option. Look at your template for that control to make sure there's nothing in there causing the lack of stretch. It's a simple layout architecture issue but you'll just have to find the culprit causing it. Worse case scenario, you can bind the width the ActualWidth of another object.